# Naming conventions with pivot function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot

The code I'm using is below. The issue is that the items I'm pivoting on go last in the naming convention. I.E `null_pdiv_spend`, `null_pdiv_visits`. I would like to have the naming convention be `spend_null_pdiv` to coincide with the rest of my tables. Please advise.

```
pivot(
    count(x) as visits,
    sum(y) as spend,
    sum(c) as items,
    sum(b) as mkdn

    for pdiv_cd in (
    '@@@' as null_pdiv,
    '010' as hbags_acc,
    '011' as fine_jewelry,
    '070' as pdiv_70
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another level of subquery, and rename the columns with aliases:

```
select null_pdiv_spend as spend_null_pdiv,
  null_pdiv_visits as visits_null_pdiv,
  ...
from (
  select *
  from (
    ...
  )
  pivot(count(x) as visits, sum(y) as spend, sum(c) as items, sum(b) as mkdn
    for (pdiv_cd) in (
      '@@@' as null_pdiv,
      '010' as hbags_acc,
      '011' as fine_jewelry,
      '070' as pdiv_70
    )
  )
)
```

That lets you modify the order of the columns in the result set too, if that matters to you.